# Perl: Array of Array References

Tags: perl, dereference

Might be repeated somewhere but i've looked at every perl array referencing / dereferencing example i've been able to find and tried running 10+ different combos of this string to get my desired output. Such as @$array[i], @{$array[i]}, @{@$array[i]} etc.

So I have an array of array references. I built this by creating a global array, and then I push smaller temp arrays into that global array. The final outcome looks something like this when Dumper() is ran.

```
$VAR1 = [ 1 ]; $VAR2 = []; $VAR3 = []; $VAR4 = []; $VAR5 = []; $VAR6 = []; $VAR7 = [ 1 ]; $VAR8 = []; $VAR9 = []; $VAR10 = []; $VAR11 = [ 1 ]; $VAR12 = []; $VAR13 = [ 1 ]; $VAR14 = []; $VAR15 = [ 1 ];
```

Now I am trying to dereference one of these arrays by using

```
my @arrayRef = @{$redArray[$i]};
print "Here: " . @arrayRef[0];
```

@redArray is my global array.

The @{$redArray[$i]} part I see as get the reference from the global array, and then deference it which should return as array like [] or [1] or [1,1 .....]

Then on line two I want to get the first element of the array, which would return nothing/error or 1.

When print "Here: " . @arrayRef[0]; runs though, the output I see is

```
Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here: Here:
```

Comment: FYI, the output from Data::Dumper is easier to read if you pass it a reference. Instead of `print Dumper @foo;` do `print Dumper \@foo;`

Comment: Thanks good tip, i'll try using that a bit. [ [], [], [], [], [], [], [ 1 ], [], [], [], [ 1 ], [], [ 1 ], [], [ 1 ] ];

Comment: You should read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html

Comment: Note that in `print "Here: " . @arrayRef[0];`, it should be written as `$arrayRef[0]`. This would have been pointed out if you have `use warnings;` enabled. To further, double-quotes interpolate, so it can be shortened a bit: `print "Here: $arrayRef[0]";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you're getting confused as to when you should use the $ and @ symbols.  (To be fair, it's not always obvious in Perl.)  The Perl reference tutorial link glenn gave is the best resource.  Maybe some examples will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @important_years = (1066, 1492, 1776);
my @recent_years    = (2010, 2012, 2014);

my $important_years_ref = \@important_years;
my $recent_years_ref    = \@recent_years;

my @redArray = ($important_years_ref, $recent_years_ref);

printf("%s\n", $redArray[0][0]);    # 1066
printf("%s\n", $redArray[0][1]);    # 1492
printf("%s\n", $redArray[0][2]);    # 1776

printf("%s\n", $redArray[1][0]);    # 2010
printf("%s\n", $redArray[1][1]);    # 2012
printf("%s\n", $redArray[1][2]);    # 2014

# Get a reference to the "important years" array
my $important_years_copy_ref = $redArray[0];
printf("%s\n", $important_years_copy_ref->[2]);  # 1776

# Or make brand new array by dereferencing
# the "important years" reference stored in @redArray
my @important_years_copy = @{$redArray[0]};
printf("%s\n", $important_years_copy[2]);        # 1776
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to glenn jackman and ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was able to figure it out.

The issue is that the reference I was doing above was more or less correct but there was an error later in my code, the reference I went with was,

```
my $arrayRef = @redArray[$i];
my @redVal = @{$arrayRef};
```

Comment: Scalars are prefixed with the sigil `$`, and arrays are prefixed with `@`. So, it should be `$redArray[$i]`. And, had you been using `warnings` and `strict`, you would have been informed of this.

Comment: I am using strict and warnings. I don't see any errors due to the fact that I'm working on an ASP classic website. What would you recommend? Doing all the code first straight in perl and then copying it over? Or is there a way to dump error warnings onto a webpage?